# Cannot connect with my database using MongoClient in Node Js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am not able to connect my application with the database. My MongoDB server is running properly but I am not able to fetch data from the database.

I debugged the code and the debugger is skipping the entire code which is necessary to connect with MongoDB. Here is my code:

```
let express = require("express");
let categoryRouter = express.Router();
let mongodb = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
let url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

function router(menu) {
  categoryRouter.route("/").get(function (req, res) {
    mongodb.connect(url, function (err, dc) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send("Error While Connecting");
      } else {
        let dbObj = dc.db("may8");
        dbObj.collection("category").find().toArray(function (err, response) {
          if (err) {
            res.status(500).send("Error While Fetching");
          } else {
            res.render("category", {
              title: "Category",
              data: response,
              menu,
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });

  categoryRouter.route("/details").get(function (req, res) {
    res.send("Category Details");
  });

  return categoryRouter;
}

module.exports = router;
```

This is app.js file i am passing menu as function

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express()
let port = 7600;
let fs = require("fs");

let menu = [
  { link: "/", name: "Home" },
  { link: "/category", name: "Category" },
  { link: "/products", name: "Products" },
];

let categoryRouter = require("./src/controller/categoryRouter") (menu);
//let productRouter = require("./src/controller/productRouter")(menu);

app.use(morgan("short", { stream: fs.createWriteStream("./app.logs") }));

//static files path
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
// html file path
app.set("views", "./src/views");
// view engine name
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

//default route
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("index", { title: "Home Page", menu: menu });
});

app.use("/category", categoryRouter);
//app.use("/products", productRouter);

app.listen(port, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  else {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: How are you using the exported `router` function?

Comment: I had added app.js file plz see that file i had created an array of object whose name is menu and i am passing menu in let categoryRouter = require("./src/controller/categoryRouter") (menu);